# Android studio project doesnt build when created on D drive

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a simple Android Studio (in both Arctic Fox and Flamingo versions). File->New->New Project. Select Basic Activity. I selected **Java** and API 30 Android 11 (and also tested 29,31,32,33)

When I save the project at c:\temp\myapplication, the project can be built and run on the relevant AVD.

When I save the project at D:\temp\myapplication, I get all kinds of errors talking about Kotlin (even though I selected Java):
[image]
The D drive is NTFS formated.

When the drive was FAT (I changed it to NTFS later), I get a different kind of error:
D:\temp\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\navigation_json\debug\navigation.json (The system cannot find the path specified)

Why is this the case?

Comment: Add the path of Android Studio in environment variables (Path variable) in control panel and then try to build it.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this code:

```
android {
    .....

    defaultConfig {
      .....
      multiDexEnabled true
      }
   }
```

Comment: While possibly correct, a code-only answer helps the person who asked the question, it doesn't do them or future visitors any good.   Please consider improving your answer.